# how to pass multiple params in exec in node js

Tags: javascript, r, node.js, exec, child-process

I'm using exec library to call R-script from node js express. Below is my code :

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;

var param1 = some url;
var param2 = "hello";
var param3 = "world"
exec('Rscript pathtoscript/myScript.R"+" "+param1+" "+param2 , function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.send(error);
        }
        else if (stderr) {
            console.log(stderr);
            res.send(stderr);
        }
        else if (stdout) {
            console.log("RAN SUCCESSFULLY");
            res.json(stdout);
        }
    });
```

In the above code, if I pass only param2 and param3 the r script is able to identify it. But when I pass url, only some part of url is is getting identified as URL and rest is not (may be its long). Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more context.  What is the URL?  Is the URL [encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)?  What about the relevant sections of your R script?  Chances are that your command is malformed.  Have you tried to `console.log` your command argument to the `exec` method?  Does it work from the command line exactly as it printed?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact answer, but I hope it helps debug the issue;

What I tried to do here is double quote param1, and separate the command from the exec to make it a little easier to read.

Best of luck.

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;

var param1 = "\"http:\\something\"";
var param2 = "hello";
var param3 = "world"
var command = "Rscript pathtoscript/myScript.R "+ param1 + " " + param2 + " " + param3;

exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.send(error);
        }
        else if (stderr) {
            console.log(stderr);
            res.send(stderr);
        }
        else if (stdout) {
            console.log("RAN SUCCESSFULLY");
            res.json(stdout);
        }
    });
```

Comment: f you accept parameters from user input or web request, this can be a serious RCE, unless mitigated some way.